# View PowerPoint XML in Android as a bitmap or jpeg or png image

Tags: java, android, xml, bitmap, xpsdocument

I have many PowerPoint presentations that I need to be able to add to the res folder in my app. They will take up a lot of memory if I do not save them as XML, PDF, or XPS. PDF and android do not come together very easily at all so I choose the path of XML or XPS. I need these to be able to be viewed and/or then edited as a bitmap.

I do not understand how a PowerPoint XML is able/implemented to be viewed or drawn onto the screen. I also do not understand how I would do the same with PowerPoint XPS, but only one method(XPS or XML) is needed. I do know that PDF has slowly become not an option as to the complexity of the file and that there are no standard viewer API's.

So basically...

- I need to display/view a XML or XPS PP presentation as a bitmap on android
- I can use XML and Java
- I have done research but I still need to understand the underlying factors that go into do this implementation

I would attach code below but the size is too large for Stack Overflow. I would recommend testing with PP and save as PowerPoint XML format if you need to.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to convert to PDF once and then store it in one of image formats? Since a PDF way is at least known.

Comment: @Andrey Ermakov & Tim ... Thank for the responses. I wanted to stay away from using a PDF viewer/reader because it adds a lot of complexity to the code and a lot of times the open source frameworks do not work so well. I guess it looks to be my best option though. Too bad Adobe and Google have to be so angry with each other :( Again thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is going to be an easy way on Android for you to parse the BinaryData that is present in a powerpoint XML file.

I think you'd be better off saving your pp slides as images, that way you already have them in something that is easy to make into a Bitmap object and edit as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [HSLFSlideShow](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hslf/HSLFSlideShow.html) module on Apache.org. The module promises the ability to parse a PPT file, get the embedded objects, pictures, etc. It might help.